# Why Banks or Financial Companies prefer Oracle than other RDBMS for their "Core" systems?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql, bank

I'd like to know why most Banks or Financial companies prefer Oracle than other RDBMS for their core systems (the absolutely minimum features that a Bank must support). I found a few answers that didn't satisfy me. For example: Oracle has more features. But features for what? Can't you implement that in application level if you were not using Oracle?

Could someone please describe a bit more technical but still on high-level overview of what the bank needs and how Oracle would solve it and the others can't or don't have the features yet?

Minor question: would you use ORM if you have to develop a banking solution?

I came from the web-app (web 2.0) crowd who normally hear news about MySQL, PostgreSQL or even key-value/column-oriented storage solution. I have almost zero knowledge on how Banks or Financial companies operates from technical perspective.

Thank you,
Ed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oracle has a reputation for better reliability and security.  Historically, it has outperformed and out-scaled any other SQL engine.  This is changing, but the perception is still there.  In many markets, Oracle is still perceived as the gold standard.  Financial services seems to be one of them.

Comment: Also, when you pay oracle thousands of dollars in licensing fees, you have someone to call when things stop working.

Comment: Same is true of all the major vendors.  Microsoft has premium support offerings.  You can also buy premium support for MySQL.  More accurately, when you have invested $1 million+ for a large Oracle DB infrastructure and have built a team with the necessary expertise, as many financial institutions have, you have little incentive to throw it away as long as it keeps working.  Remember how long these guys stuck with mainframe environments.

Answer (score 10):

Corporate Culture... History... Bias...

AND Oracle is a very good DB, but so are plenty of others these days.

However, if the financial institution has been around forever, and they've used Oracle forever (since it WAS once in a class of its own), there's an investment there.

Also, since Oracle once dominated this market, people with experience in these industries are already more likely to be familiar with it and comfortable with it, so when building a new system it's a "comfortable" choice.

Comment: Good answer. Oracle is basically what Kleenex is to tissue paper, the gold standard.

Answer (score 6):

PostgreSQL is also used, Caixa (a large bank in Brazil) uses it:
[PostgreSQL in Mission-Critical Financial Systems](http://www.pgcon.org/2010/schedule/events/204.en.html)

Comment: Brazil has a federal government mandate to use open source, and Caixa is (or used to be) a government owned bank so the choice may not have been technical in nature.

Comment: You're right, but it still works great. Works better than the government itself... A company like NTT also uses PostgreSQL, they can't afford a screw up, it's their backbone.

Comment: Both of you shown an interesting fact for me who sometime happen to not know the industry outside Canada or USA. Thank you so much guys.

Comment: not a really high standard I'm afraid :) Anyway, I went through the whole "market reserve" of the 80's and 90's where no imports were allowed for "existing similar products" and the number of knock-offs of american products was mindboggling, from DOS to dBase to Wordstar. Talk about being retrograde...

Answer (score 2):

Which ever answer you receive, will most likely be biast based on the OP's personal comfort with the RDBMS used.

Any corporate entity has more measures in paperwork, *(From 1Tc to R2D2)* to fill out, and get approved when changing *working solutions* than buying a house.

So if the environment you are talking about was using Ms Access, you would find it hard to convince them to change.

Given all that, there was a time (*not to distant past/even still today*) where these kind of decisions was not made by developers, but by the costing company.

Another **joke**. Given a programmers age, Have you ever heard of [COBOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL)

Comment: Hey, COBOL is a great language.  There is even a COBOL for .NET! (http://www.netcobol.com/)

Comment: You might be surprised... I'm not even 30 years old yet but I've coded in Fortran briefly.

Comment: Geez, there's a Fortran for.NET too. (http://www.mpassociates.gr/software/distrib/science/lahey/lfnet.html).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the reasons that were mentioned Oracle is more preferred over MS SQL and other products like IBM DB, PostgreSQL and others is that:

- Oracle is the oldest since 1977, so we are talking about 37 years of
  development, while MS SQL Server since 1989 based on Sybase-SQL
  Server a joined project between MS, Ashton-Tate, and Sybase.
- Oracle has been specialized with Database development, whereas
  Microsoft was more focusing on Windows OS and Office in Addition to
  Variety of programming languages under the .Net framework, and packed under Visual Studio.
- The technical excess aspects in Oracle database over MS-SQL Server
  are mainly that Oracle is cross platform, as per database experts it
  executes queries faster, and it has two thing that MS-SQL Server
  doesn't have yet , One is **how oracle handles stored procedures** it can
  group SPs in packages so that each package with all the stores
  procedures wrapped inside it can be called as a unit and executed
  explicitly by the application, which can't be done is MS SQL Server
  so far.
- The commercial marketing of Oracle over MS SQL Server coming mainly
  from the major developers of ERP solutions for companies tends to
  prefer Oracle over MS SQL Server because it is easier to deploy and
  implement on the company's infrastructure due to that Oracle is
  cross-platform so they think it's quicker to install and run Oracle
  Database while it won't be as easy with MS SQL server Database unless the entire platform is Windows that
  depends on windows NT and .Net framework which might not be always
  used or available in the company's infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

ORACLE has a very high performance when it comes to speed. Also the capacity in some fields and has more functionality on its procedures PL/SQL. The mysql/sql server also has stored procedures but the difference is ORACLE has more functions and executes faster compared to others. It can operate more higher buffering multiple transactions on its procedures and queries. Aside from that its almost the same with the other SQL's

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is also used by for instance salesforce and amazon (http://highscalability.com/amazon-architecture) and flight reservation (http://www.dbms2.com/2010/04/21/ita-software-needlebase-google/). And Oracle can run on multiple operating systems so you are less locked than MS SQL.

A feature like flashback (http://www.oracle.com/technology/deploy/availability/htdocs/Flashback_Overview.htm) is very hard to implement in the client. Hash joins, analytical queries and materialized views are not stuff the client can do if you don't want to retrieve all the data from the database because that takes too much time. I've understood that mysql can't do a hash join. Oracle can also automatically parrallelize long running queries.

There is also support for changing the database schema without going offline.

Oracle has also features for encryption and data security (even on row level).

I don't think that financial companies are going to use non-acid nosql systems. Maybe for logging but not for the "important" stuff. Maybe some use Berkeley DB because Berkeley DB has transactions.

Comment: Yes, I know for sure they're not going to go to NoSQL route. They probably will for logging and a few analytical/data mining/warehouse tasks. But that would only happen in the far future and will still use  RDBMS at its core.